# please help insert data into database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, sqlconnection

This is my code but it gives me error I'll write below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using lanox;

public partial class Info : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDataSource1"].ConnectionString);
            Connection.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from products where UserName='"+txtName.Text+"'";
           // SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(checkuser,Connection);

            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("User Eneter invalid value ");
            }

            Connection.Close(); 
        }
    }

    protected void btnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
               SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDataSource1"].ConnectionString);
                Connection.Open();
                string insert = "insert into products (ID,FirstName,LastName) values (@User,@F,@L)";
                SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(insert, Connection);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", txtID);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@F", txtName);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L", txtLast);

                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Response.Redirect("Info.aspx");
                Response.Write("Connection Sucssesfull");

                Connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I get error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Command' does not exist in the current context
>
> Source Error:
>   Line 23:             int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

Comment: If you expect people to put their time into helping answer your question, the very least you can do is put the time in to format your question, and code, correctly.  The question preview exists exactly for that reason.  Use it.

Comment: So - can we have some details of the error ?

Comment: Sir im new here i dont know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You will have to declare your command object globally as:

```
 SqlCommand Command=null;
```

**OR**

**Remove the comment on pageload for:**

```
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(checkuser,Connection);
```

This will solve your proble.

The whole code will be:

```
public partial class Info : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlCommand Command=null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (IsPostBack)
        {
      SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDataSource1"].ConnectionString);
            Connection.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from products where UserName='"+txtName.Text+"'";

             //If you dont want to declare globally , remove below comment

           // SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(checkuser,Connection);

            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("User Eneter invalid value ");

            }


            Connection.Close(); 


        }
    }
    protected void btnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (IsPostBack)
            {
               SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDataSource1"].ConnectionString);
                Connection.Open();
                string insert = "insert into products (ID,FirstName,LastName) values (@User,@F,@L)";
                Command = new SqlCommand(insert, Connection);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", txtID);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@F", txtName);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L", txtLast);
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("Info.aspx");
                Response.Write("Connection Sucssesfull");

                Connection.Close();

            }



        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It gave me another error it says                                       "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."                   SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDataSource1"].ConnectionString);